# pgfplots - lack of one bar

Tags: pgfplots

I want to make a chart with nine bars. As you can see they are in the code (0-8). Unfortunately it's making only eight bars.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pgfplotsset{width=14cm,compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x tick label style={
/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ylabel=Prawdopodobieństwo,
enlargelimits=0.02,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
anchor=north,legend=-1},
ybar interval=0.8,
]
\addplot 
coordinates{
(0,0.00390625)
(1,0.03125)
(2,0.109375)
(3,0.21875)
(4,0.273438)
(5,0.21875)
(6,0.109375)
(7,0.03125)
(8,0.00390625)
};
\addplot 
coordinates{
(0,0.00405)
(1,0.03143)
(2,0.10847)
(3,0.21984)
(4,0.2723)
(5,0.2166)
(6,0.11272)
(7,0.03062)
(8,0.00397)
};
\addplot 
coordinates{
(0,0.00261035)
(1,0.0237304)
(2,0.107973)
(3,0.221879)
(4,0.270052)
(5,0.22449)
(6,0.108685)
(7,0.0363075)
(8,0.00427148)
};
\legend{Rozklad teoretyczny,Rozklad dla n=100000,Rozklad dla n=4214}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me if I change `ybar interval=0.8` to just `ybar` and remove `enlargelimits=0.02`. I guess you may need to adjust the settings a little more carefully starting from a working plot and going toward what you want.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use the `ybar interval` style, you need to supply an extra "dummy datapoint" to each plot. This is necessary because the interval style is used for plotting bars over ranges, not at points, so in order to calculate the width of the last range, you need to supply an upper limit.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pgfplotsset{width=14cm,compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar interval,
x tick label style={
/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ylabel=Prawdopodobieństwo,
enlargelimits=0.02,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
anchor=north,legend=-1},
]
\addplot 
coordinates{
(0,0.00390625)
(1,0.03125)
(2,0.109375)
(3,0.21875)
(4,0.273438)
(5,0.21875)
(6,0.109375)
(7,0.03125)
(8,0.00390625)
(9,0)
};
\addplot 
coordinates{
(0,0.00405)
(1,0.03143)
(2,0.10847)
(3,0.21984)
(4,0.2723)
(5,0.2166)
(6,0.11272)
(7,0.03062)
(8,0.00397)
(9,0)
};
\addplot 
coordinates{
(0,0.00261035)
(1,0.0237304)
(2,0.107973)
(3,0.221879)
(4,0.270052)
(5,0.22449)
(6,0.108685)
(7,0.0363075)
(8,0.00427148)
(9,0)
};
\legend{Rozklad teoretyczny,Rozklad dla n=100000,Rozklad dla n=4214}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ybar interval plot]

Alternatively, you can just use the `ybar` style. In that case, you should use `enlarge y limits=0.02` instead of `enlargelimits=0.02` to make sure that no bars are cut off at the sides. Notice especially the difference in the tick marks and the vertical dividing lines in the resulting plot.

[image: ybar plot]